# How can I use PhpStorm to seamlessly connect my php to my database?

Tags: phpstorm

I've setup and integrated my SQL database to my PhpStorm project; it'll auto complete and suggest database objects and such anywhere in my code.

With that said, is there a way I can connect my PHP to the DB without the usual

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";
```

block of code? Some feature, specific plugin, or method via PhpStorm?

Essentially looking for the simplest way to `INSERT` data from my PHP script into the DB.